# Snap point features based on attributes of another feature class - ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor, python-script-tool

I am trying to snap a point feature class to another point feature class based on matching attributes.
I have a script tool built and it works for a sample area where all records match, however when trying to run the entire dataset it will fail when it hits a row that cannot be found/matched.

I'd like this script to iterate through each row in pts_Survey and see if there is a match to the attributes in pts_MDP.

If there is a match, update the geometry of pts_Survey to snap to the geometry of pts_MDP.

How can I change the script to account for this?
Can I add an IF statement or should I consider re-working the code entirely?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Check out the spatial extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

pts_MDP = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
id_MDP = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
pts_Survey = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
id_Survey = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

pts_Defined = {str(row[0]):row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(pts_MDP,[id_MDP,"SHAPE@"])}
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pts_Survey,[id_Survey,"SHAPE@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor: # loop through points
        row[1] = pts_Defined[str(row[0])] # move point geometry to match point geometry from dictionary

    cursor.updateRow(row) # update the geometry
```

Comment: change `row[1] = pts_Defined[str(row[0])]` to `row[1] = pts_Defined.get(str(row[0]), row[1])`. dict.get returns a corresponding value or a given value if key is missing. So when you hit a missing id, you'll just save the initial geometry. Also you should move cursor.updateRow one level up.

Comment: Serge, this worked perfectly!
You should post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `row[1] = pts_Defined[str(row[0])]` to `row[1] = pts_Defined.get(str(row[0]), row[1])` dict.get returns a corresponding value or a given value if key is missing. So when you hit a missing id you'll just save the initial geometry. Also you should move `cursor.updateRow(row)` one level up
Another option:

```
row[1] = pts_Defined.get(str(row[0]), None)
if row[1] is None:
    cursor.deleteRow()
else:
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This will update geometry if corresponding ID exists or delete record if not.